# Camera acceptance button id - how to find it?

Tags: android, android-camera, keyevent

I have an app that after taking photo needs acceptance likt this:
[image]

and I can't found keyevent that click that accept button. Tried almost half of the available ones - since the other half is for game pad buttons or pilot remotes. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: May be you need to create a BroadcastReceiver , which will receive the Camera Events.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't found keyevent that click that accept button

There is no `KeyEvent` for either of the buttons shown in your screenshot. Those are presumably `ImageButton` widgets. You call `setOnClickListener()` on them to register an `OnClickListener` to find out when they are clicked.

Comment: Oh, hello CommonsWare. I have Your guide, but haven't reached camera section yet :)

Well, those buttons are from phone's camera, not the app, so I can't make it.

Comment: @user2570350: If you are saying that your screenshot is from the camera app on your device, then you need to be using `startActivityForResult()` to launch the camera app and `onActivityResult()` to find out whether the user accepted the image or not.

Comment: I haven't said that I need that for Calabash testing. So, when user accepts photo then I will get this button id? I'm not so good in coding right now...

Comment: @user2570350: Um, I am not aware of any way for you to find out the ID of a button from an app that is not yours. If Calabash offers other ways of identifying the button, you could use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to inspect the UI of that activity and see if you can find the matching information for that button (e.g., `android:contentDescription`).

Comment: Just found that: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/camera/Camera.java#Camera and there is a button with btn_done id, but doesn't seem to be working or I am missing something.

Comment: @user2570350: There are thousands of Android device models. There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of different camera apps that ship on those device models. This one certainly is not the AOSP camera app, which has never looked like that.

Comment: The funny thing is that the back button (on the left) can be performed with keyevent #4...

Comment: @user2570350: "keyevent #4" is the BACK button. It may well be that pressing the OS's BACK button and pressing that left-hand button on the screen *have the same effect*. However, "keyevent #4" is not triggering that left-hand button itself.